# Crontab not running a shell script but works with command line

Tags: linux, cron

My question is about running a simple shell script using crontab. Crontab is successfully running one command like :

```
* * * * * echo "test" >> /home/user/Bureau/testcron
```

But not the other for another shell script which is :

```
* * * * * /bin/bash /home/user/Bureau/createemails
```

Comment: first thing first check your script does have executable permission or not

Comment: The script doesn't need to have the execute bits set if it's being invoked as an argument to /bin/bash.

Comment: Without knowing the contents of `/home/user/Bureau/createemails`, I would guess that you are using relative paths.  However, cron doesn't run jobs from the user's home directory.  Either do an explicit `cd /home/user` in the script or use absolute paths.

Comment: I did add already the absolute bath of bash . When i did edit crontab with : 'sudo crontab -e' , i did add these two lines after comments  : 'SHELL=/bin/bash' and : 'PATH=/sbin:/bin:/accnt1/sbin:/usr/bin' , but still not working ...

Comment: Is your user allowed to send mails?

Comment: I don t know realy , how to check that ?

Comment: do you mean if crontab can send email to user ?

Comment: I did add the email line in 'crontab -e' like : 'MAILTO=mymail@gmail.com' , after the line : 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin' , but it send nothing ..

Comment: can you post content of `/home/user/Bureau/createemails` in your question ?

Comment: sure , here is it code : '#!/bin/bash

Comment: sure , here is it code : #!/bin/bash        for i in *          do            echo $i          done          for i in 'seq 1 30' ; do echo "nom$i@domain.com" >> emails; done

Answer (score 0):

Now it is working fine , i had to put the absolute path of the file wishing to be created from the script .